# Clique-Width - Confusion over Proof

Tags: graph-theory

I am working through some Graph Theory notes, and do not understand a line from the proof of a Theorem. Here is the statement of the Theorem.

> $cw(G)=max\{cw(H)$ : *$H$ is a prime induced subgraph of $G$*$\}$.

The proof uses induction on $n=|V(G)|$ and starts by dealing with the case that $G$ is prime itself, which is easy to follow. It then continues as follows:

> Let $G$ be non-prime, and let $M_{1},...M_{p}$ be maximal non-trivial modules of $G$. By contracting each $M_{i}$ into a single vertex $m_{i}$ we obtain the characteristic graph $G_{0}$ of $G$. We separately  construct expressions representing the graphs $G_{0}$ and $G[M_{i}]$ for each i, assuming by the induction that each expression uses at most $max\{cw(H)$ : *$H$ is a prime induced subgraph of $G$*$\}$ different labels. If in the expression defining $G_{0}$ the vertex $m_{i}$ is created with label $j$, we finish the construction of the graph $G[M_{i}]$ by renaming all labels to $j$. Then in the tree describing $G_{0}$ we replace the node creating $m_{i}$ with the root of the tree creating $G[M_{i}]$. The resulting tree represents $G$ and uses at most $max\{cw(H)$ : *$H$ is a prime induced subgraph of $G$*$\}$ labels, as required. $\square$

Ok so here are my thoughts. It agree that the construction of each $G[M_{i}]$ requires at most $max\{cw(H) \space : \space H$ is a prime induced subgraph of $G\}$ labels, by the induction hypothesis and the fact that any prime induced subgraph of $G[M_{i}]$ is a prime induced subgraph of $G$. But when constructing $G$ by taking the construction of $G_{0}$ and 'editing' in the sub-constructions of the $G[M_{i}]$, we have to make sure that the labels used in construction of each $G[M_{i}]$ have not already been used in the construction of $G$. For instance, when we come to the creation of the last vertex $m_{p}$ of $G_{0}$, although we may only need less than or equal to the required number of labels for the construction $G[M_{p}]$, these labels have to be chosen to not 'clash' with the labels occupied by the previous $m_{i}$, so we cannot be sure we are not using too many labels?

Would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks

Misha:

[image]

Comment: "so that we are all on the same page" - except for the people using screen readers, to whom all of your latest questions read like absolute nonsense. Perhaps you could put a bit more effort into your questions, and type things out instead of including screenshots?

Comment: Well forgive me for not thinking of this possibility. In fact I didn't know what a screen reader was until I just looked it up. Nothing to do with lack of effort, to me the questions looked very presentable, so I naturally assumed that they would to others. That in conjunction with the fact that the screenshots clearly saved a lot of typing, I thought why not? But I take your point, and I'll re-type them. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Screen readers aren't the only issue; the question also becomes less valuable to the network, because a lot of the text won't be findable by searching. If it makes you feel better about the effort, I am going to answer this question once it's typed up.

Comment: Ok now I know. Thanks, I have almost finished editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the point of view of the formula:**

If $X$ is an expression for creating $G[M_i]$, then $\rho_{1 \to j}(\rho_{2 \to j}(\dots \rho_{k \to j}(X)\dots))$ is an expression for creating a $G[M_i]$ with all vertices labeled $j$.

In the description for $G_0$, if we replace the vertex creation $j (m_i)$ with the expression $\rho_{1 \to j}(\rho_{2 \to j}(\dots \rho_{k \to j}(X)\dots))$, then instead of creating a single vertex $m_i$ with label $j$, we'll get all of $G[M_i]$. Then, because the labels are the same, the edges between $G[M_i]$ and the rest of $G$ will all be the same as the edges between $m_i$ and the rest of $G_0$, exactly what we want from a module.

Order of operations ensures that whatever happens in $\rho_{1 \to j}(\rho_{2 \to j}(\dots \rho_{k \to j}(X)\dots))$ does not affect the rest of the formula.

**From the point of view of the tree:**

The creation of $G[M_1], G[M_2], \dots$ are happening in separate subtrees. When we do a relabeling $\rho_{i \to j}$, a edge join $\eta_{i,j}$, or anything else, that node only affects the things in the subtree below it. So we don't have to worry about the same labels being used for a different purpose in another subtree.

And no matter if we're looking at a single $j(m_i)$ node, or a complicated subtree creating a uniformly $j$-labeled $G[M_i]$, the next thing we see above it is a disjoint union node connecting it to the rest of the graph. That is what separates labels in the subtree from labels used anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you Misha. I think I understand. To test this, can you please imagine a tree with vertices $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ and degree sequence $(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)$ where $a,b,c$ are leaves and $g$ has degree $3$. Would the following be an example of a valid $3$-expression, where the labels $1$ and $2$ are reused?: $\eta_{3,2}(3(g)\oplus\eta_{2,1}(2(f)\oplus1(c))\oplus\eta_{2,1}(2(e)\oplus1(b) )\oplus \eta_{2,1}(2(d)\oplus1(a)))$

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You make the labeled graphs $a^1 - d^2$, $b^1 - e^2$, $c^1 - f^2$ and $g^3$, put them together, and join $g$ to $d, e, f$. (For building the tree, we'd want to parenthesize the $\oplus$ operations, I think, but the order doesn't really matter.)

Comment: I've added a tree to describe this tree as an edit to the original question. Please could you verify if it is ok? Thanks again Misha.

Comment: Two things about the tree: first, it should be clearly a rooted tree, and yours doesn't look that way. Second, the $\eta_{i,j}$ nodes shouldn't be leaves; they should have a child, which is a graph to which we apply the $\eta_{i,j}$ transformation. Here's what the tree could look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS1Ty.png

Comment: Ok, got it now!